# MobileService Client Facebook Login fails

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin, authentication, azure-mobile-services

since a few days we are running into an issue with our facebook login through mobile service client.

we use facebook single-sign-on to get a valid usertoken with several permissions and pass it to our mobileservice. this fails since a few days.

here we go with our valid token:

```
MobileServiceClient ms = Mvx.Resolve<MobileServiceClient>();
                    var accessTokenJSONObject = JObject.FromObject(new { access_token = _fbAccessToken });
                    MobileServiceUser user = await ms.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, accessTokenJSONObject);
                    _mainLoginViewModel.FacebookLogin(user);
```

The ms.LoginAsync fails with

```
 {System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream
```

do you guys have any ideas to get this back on working?

thank you in advance

Comment: For an explanation why it fails, see the duplicate. You likely need to either adapt your configuration, to use at least API v2.3, or you might need to update the framework/SDK you are using itself (if that wasn’t prepared for this long-announced change yet.)

Comment: Azure Mobile Apps Authentication has already been fixed for the v2.3 graph API.   If it isn't working for you, open a support case or post to Azure Forums.